# Rotating images between Divs

Tags: jquery

I am trying to rotate some images inside some divs. Here's where I have reached so far with my limited jquery skills.

```
<div id='pos-1'>
</div>
<div id='pos-2'>
</div>
<div id='pos-3'>
</div>


var image = new Array ();
  image[0] = "<img src='https://placehold.it/200/09f/fff.png'/></a>";
  image[1] = "<img src='https://placehold.it/200/000/fff.png'/></a>";
  image[2] = "<img src='https://placehold.it/200/22f/000.png'/></a>";
  image[3] = "<img src='https://placehold.it/200/32f/fff.png'/></a>";
  image[4] = "<img src='https://placehold.it/200/42f/fff.png'/></a>";

var link = new Array ();
    link[0] = "<a href='http://www.jquery.com'>";
    link[1] = "<a href='http://www.microsoft.com'>";
    link[2] = "<a href='http://www.yahoo.com'>";
    link[3] = "<a href='http://www.msn.com'>";
    link[4] = "<a href='http://www.stackoverflow.com'>";

var size = image.length;
var x = Math.floor(size*Math.random());
$('#pos-1').append(link[x]+image[x]);
$('#pos-2').append(link[x]+image[x]);
$('#pos-3').append(link[x]+image[x]);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/y0hga2of/

Here the image is associated with the link so that once the user clicks on the div, he/she is taken to that url. Eg: image0 is associated with link0, image1 with link1 and so on.

However with this code, the same image shows in all the divs. What I want is

- image0 and link0 should display in pos-1
- image1/link1 and image2/link2 should 'rotate' in pos-2
- image3/link3 and image4/link4 should rotate in pos-3

Also currently I want to display only one image in pos-1. At a later stage, I may rotate two images as well in pos-1. Similarly I may display only one image in pos-2. How do I accommodate this flexibility in my code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this as per your need:

[jsfiddle.net/y0hga2of/5/](https://jsfiddle.net/y0hga2of/5/)

```
$(function(){
var image = new Array ();
  image[0] = "<img src='https://placehold.it/200/09f/fff.png'/></a>";
  image[1] = "<img src='https://placehold.it/200/000/fff.png'/></a>";
  image[2] = "<img src='https://placehold.it/200/22f/000.png'/></a>";
  image[3] = "<img src='https://placehold.it/200/32f/fff.png'/></a>";
  image[4] = "<img src='https://placehold.it/200/42f/fff.png'/></a>";

var link = new Array ();
    link[0] = "<a href='http://www.jquery.com'>";
    link[1] = "<a href='http://www.microsoft.com'>";
    link[2] = "<a href='http://www.yahoo.com'>";
    link[3] = "<a href='http://www.msn.com'>";
    link[4] = "<a href='http://www.stackoverflow.com'>";

  var min = 0;
  var max = 1;
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
  $('#pos-1').append(link[x]+image[x]);

  min=1;
  max=3;
  x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
  $('#pos-2').append(link[x]+image[x]);

  min=3;
  max=5;
  x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
  $('#pos-3').append(link[x]+image[x]);
});
```

Comment: Can you change your answer as per https://jsfiddle.net/y0hga2of/5/ so that I can mark it as answer and close this question. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same value of the random `x` for the three append statements, you need to recalculate `x` each time as following:

```
var x = Math.floor(size*Math.random());
$('#pos-1').append(link[x]+image[x]);
x = Math.floor(size*Math.random());
$('#pos-2').append(link[x]+image[x]);
x = Math.floor(size*Math.random());
$('#pos-3').append(link[x]+image[x]);
```

see the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y0hga2of/1/)

Comment: Thanks. How will this code ensure that image1/link1 and image2/link2 should 'rotate' is shown only in pos-2?

Comment: rotate means that you need to set an interval to change it every selected amount of time, and choose only from 2 or 3 (in pos-2), so you don't need random anymore; just check the value and replace it.
See this update [fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/y0hga2of/4/)

Comment: with rotate I meant on a page refresh it should rotate image. Sorry if I was not clear.

Comment: Do you mean that at each page refresh it should always change? or randomly show one of only these two?